# How do you switch from one file window to another in Dreamweaver CS3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, text-editors

**I am really bugged** I am updating a website and would like to stay on the keyboard when I change from one file to another in the Dreamweaver editor. I have searched the help files; rather get my teeth drilled, but to no avail. I had a computer professor who would scold you everytime you left the keyboard and reached for the mouse. She was right. It is much faster to stay on the keyboard. Control what? This is my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no specific experience with Dreamweaver, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is common in MDI interfaces as is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> so both would be worth trying.

Comment: Thank you, I looked in the menu commands dialog again and found that you are right. I hate help files, but this time they HELPED.
Control - Tab works.... thanks again.